# Connect iPhone to USB HardDrive

Tags: ios

I have a unique situation at my company.  We are trying to develop a mobile service app that connects to slot machines.  If you connect a PC to the slot machine, an external HD pops up in Windows and you can copy files to it.

We want to do the same thing through an iPad.

I know this would be all custom code, but I was wondering if it was possible for iOS to read an external USB drive through it's doc connector.

Answer (score 1):

No. iOS/iPad is only able to act as a USB host with the Camera Connection Kit ([Apple Store](http://store.apple.com/us/product/MC531ZM/A)). Even then, it only works to import/export pictures and videos between the iPad and camera.

Comment: So no possibility of custom code against a hardware device?  Or are you commenting that it's not possible out of the box?

Answer (score 1):

It may be overkill in your situation, but take a look at the Apple's APIs for programming [External Accessories](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ExternalAccessoryPT/Introduction/Introduction.html) (ADC link). It may require changes to the hardware, but may serve your needs for use with future devices.

Comment: Yah, We will be writing a custom app for sure, you think you'd be able to code something with file access.

Comment: File access is generally a no-no on iOS device. That's part of the tradeoff for iOS stability. But maybe you can get around it a bit with the accessory stuff.

Comment: Not file access on the device.  File access through the USB cable to an external device.